Why does Prettier wrap my anonymous function with another anonymous function call and how do I turn it off?
Here is the original code:
namespace.namespace2 = new function() {/* logic here*/}

After using Prettier:
namespace.namespace2 = new (function() {/* logic here*/})();

Why? I want an option to disable this, but can't find it documented anywhere.
I went into the Prettier playground area on their site, put in the code from the example above, and fiddled around with all settings, nothing worked.
I've then searched through the Prettier documentation, obviously tried to search for an answer, but I could only find posts unrelated to my issue.

Remove the new keyword.

@Davi this changes the behavior of the code.

@JSONDerulo Possibly, but the new keyword is the reason why prettier wraps the function with an IIFE. Try it with the above snippet in the prettier online playground

@Davi you can try it out very easily in any JavaScript environment. With the new keyword, namespace.namespace2 will contain an object, but without it will contain a function.

@JSONDerulo I meant to try out prettier's behaviour. Of course namespace2 contains an object. Without seeing the body of the function (I guess that it is not empty in reality), there's now way to know for sure what sideeffects it has to remove the new (and hence if it is OK to do it or what else to change). The question was "Why does Prettier ... and how do I turn it off?", and one possible way to turn it off is to remove the new.

"new Foo is equivalent to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called without arguments." Prettier is an opinionated formatter, which strives for consistency, in this case always including the parentheses. There's still only one anonymous function in what you're showing.

@jonrsharpe extending your comment with a simplified example and comparing it to the code in the question would qualify as a complete answer to this question in my opinion.

@Davi unfortunately, removing the new keyword breaks our codebase, so it's not an option.

This works as intended and was introduced with prettier v1.17.0. For more information about the reasons, see the pull request and linked issues. To summarize: It enforces a consistent syntax. There is no configuration option to change this behavior, and prettier won't add such an option, see prettier's option philosophy.
